# PyCryptoDome AES CBC documentation code gives different output

Tags: python, aes, cbc-mode, pycryptodome

I am using the code presented in the [documentation](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/classic.html#cbc-mode) of the PyCryptoDome AES CBC documentation.

```
import json
from base64 import b64encode
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Util.Padding import pad
from Crypto.Random import get_random_bytes

data = b"secret"
key = get_random_bytes(16)
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC)
ct_bytes = cipher.encrypt(pad(data, AES.block_size))
iv = b64encode(cipher.iv).decode('utf-8')
ct = b64encode(ct_bytes).decode('utf-8')
result = json.dumps({'iv':iv, 'ciphertext':ct})
print(result)
```

The expected output is:

```
{"iv": "bWRHdzkzVDFJbWNBY0EwSmQ1UXFuQT09", "ciphertext": "VDdxQVo3TFFCbXIzcGpYa1lJbFFZQT09"}
```

But the output I am getting (Same copy-pasted code is):

```
{"iv": "PnMwNa/dPBGSkg5LeJ++1g==", "ciphertext": "OGTvHSp2O4dGgfbKbXpSzA=="}
```

I thought the issue might be caused by the random key, so I run it 20 times in a loop:

```
import json
from base64 import b64encode
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Util.Padding import pad
from Crypto.Random import get_random_bytes

print('Result should be like\n{"iv": "bWRHdzkzVDFJbWNBY0EwSmQ1UXFuQT09", "ciphertext": "VDdxQVo3TFFCbXIzcGpYa1lJbFFZQT09"}')

for x in range(0, 20):
    data = b"secret"
    key = get_random_bytes(16)
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC)
    ct_bytes = cipher.encrypt(pad(data, AES.block_size))
    iv = b64encode(cipher.iv).decode('utf-8')
    ct = b64encode(ct_bytes).decode('utf-8')
    result = json.dumps({'iv':iv, 'ciphertext':ct})
    print(result)
```

Sadly, all the results were similar:

```
Result should be like
{"iv": "bWRHdzkzVDFJbWNBY0EwSmQ1UXFuQT09", "ciphertext": "VDdxQVo3TFFCbXIzcGpYa1lJbFFZQT09"}
{"iv": "PnMwNa/dPBGSkg5LeJ++1g==", "ciphertext": "OGTvHSp2O4dGgfbKbXpSzA=="}
{"iv": "FR9GQqA3tssPKn2YHhHe4w==", "ciphertext": "FM3CLY51i0Gvctr9efXGDg=="}
{"iv": "ocsVcOggvjUXj8s2IHXbUg==", "ciphertext": "mR3mYEK4M3QhtUmPt6jwuA=="}
{"iv": "TCox/Pfv5Xjkrm8z3weJ0w==", "ciphertext": "DkkGKXvXpV4B8pV5B4ctxw=="}
{"iv": "eZvCrk97EC4eL1kO5PQ+Dg==", "ciphertext": "idaLj7wl/F79qUdzZodbBg=="}
{"iv": "KqwaWZTxU5ZFn6Ekq/wWEg==", "ciphertext": "A25LP0wNTJRkndhvuhuasw=="}
{"iv": "FlFNCnQHmUajP2jNDvIiLw==", "ciphertext": "T9vOu0z9DkUrXCUGqXacxw=="}
{"iv": "U74vTvWZNhKbp5sq9uT9Sg==", "ciphertext": "vfJ1Brftb897O6xTMI3MQg=="}
{"iv": "tIVgKly8wyhpwdoRQ6SzqA==", "ciphertext": "EjnyNuIPVmt7cnEaFSsoww=="}
{"iv": "5qoVwEB7WfHGSGZvHY25Hg==", "ciphertext": "RBxS7gIMAfZqS5a9vTEcjQ=="}
{"iv": "NCHdCr09s9pMQsHK+4ECjA==", "ciphertext": "V8ezqaw8WrrygrokrD48ew=="}
{"iv": "x+T+fM3diahDBie4o7fvpA==", "ciphertext": "0xnjaIArYsfKn5JkjXnniQ=="}
{"iv": "v0r3123VCkZy7zOVixyBkA==", "ciphertext": "J2U0MEHqDEwC45UCY7+SdA=="}
{"iv": "l1iA//cLxESUax39ZanyRw==", "ciphertext": "QLC74BydGuQ1J73PUvKl+Q=="}
{"iv": "FcsfeZ3iCrVVaRsZSm3Gsw==", "ciphertext": "wyiZEo1VpdM/u+ucstzn6Q=="}
{"iv": "av6FSkAzfkOyfLvxDIHY9g==", "ciphertext": "EuexPtCb69+37F9INqWemw=="}
{"iv": "a8F+8OEv1ieHcgwMXocEww==", "ciphertext": "6rd04diPiA7tw/4MgIJsWw=="}
{"iv": "jUY115jhERX2KI+dtVajlQ==", "ciphertext": "TRC5RR3qX6EDjjH1kmO6ew=="}
{"iv": "fcW66kw4gpEWRvNf3AQg7g==", "ciphertext": "o1G6luiDT1Cf2bmZlTu57A=="}
{"iv": "U5FbVnDONa0h4Q6PDJo60A==", "ciphertext": "ilGJKuKNxUxx/Lxz5N85NQ=="}
```

So, my question is, what could be possibly causing this mismatch?
Also, please note that the IV size is wrong compared to the expected output

Comment: As long as you do not specify an IV, a random IV will be generated (see the PyCryptodome doc). A random IV and/or a random key will produce different ciphertexts for the same plaintext. In this sense, `{"iv": "bWRH...", "ciphertext": "VDdx..."}` is not the _expected_ result, but a _possible_ result. However, the IV in the posted example /  PyCryptodome  doc has the wrong size (a bug in the doc). For AES, the IV is 16 bytes long or 24 bytes Base64 encoded. I.e. the code works correctly.

Comment: For AES encryption in CBC mode it is essential that the same IV must never be reused. To prevent inexperienced user to do so the PyCryptoDome function is using a randomly generated IV - that is what you get as output for each round. Second: You didn't explain where your "expected" IV is coming from - it is a Base64 encoded value of a (**already**) Base64 encoded output. When Base64 decoding your expected value you get "mdGw93T1ImcAcA0Jd5QqnA==" that decoded perfectly to 16 byte long IV (in hex string encoding 99d1b0f774f5226700700d0977942a9c) so everything is fine with your function.

Comment: Also the ciphertext `VDdx...` has the wrong size. IV and ciphertext are _double_ Base64 encoded. But the code (as your tests show) outputs IV and ciphertext only _single_ Base64 encoded. So the posted output is not consistent with the code. As said, a bug in the documentation.

Comment: @Topaco you said there was a bug in the doc (wrong size), you also said that the code works correctly, do you have an example I can run with an expected output size?
Also by expected output I meant expected output size follow the doc instructions.

Comment: Or is there another library you suggest I should use?

Comment: The code and your output, e.g. `{"iv": "PnMw...", "ciphertext": "OGTv..."}` are **correct**, the IV and the ciphertext (for the plaintext `secret`) are 16 bytes long and 24 bytes Base64 encoded respectively. Only the example posted in the documentation `{"iv": "bWRH...", "ciphertext": "VDdx..."}` is wrong and contains the _double_ instead of the _single_ base64 encoded values. There is no reason to change the library because of this.

Comment: assuming the code works, I ran it and got these results
`Key b'\xe6\xc8\xe5\x1bn\xa0)\x15\x1eU7\x8fk\xd8\xb0lJ\x83T\x02\x89j\xa0\xa9'
{"iv": "tSS7DkPNk3u327048hYr9w==", "ciphertext": "i71oZoTk7aKxckhcbGCSEg=="}`
any advice on how I can decode these in an online tool? (such as this one for example https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/aes-encryption-decryption)

Comment: It is easier if you output the key hex encoded (e.g. with `hex()`): `e6c8e51b6ea029151e55378f6bd8b06c4a835402896aa0a9`. A suitable online tool is [CyberChef](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=From_Base64('A-Za-z0-9%2B/%3D',true)AES_Decrypt(%7B'option':'Hex','string':'e6c8e51b6ea029151e55378f6bd8b06c4a835402896aa0a9'%7D,%7B'option':'Base64','string':'tSS7DkPNk3u327048hYr9w%3D%3D'%7D,'CBC','Raw','Raw',%7B'option':'Hex','string':''%7D,%7B'option':'Hex','string':''%7D)&input=aTcxb1pvVGs3YUt4Y2toY2JHQ1NFZz09).

Comment: Note that the key has 24 bytes (AES-192), i.e. you can't have used the above code because it applies a 16 bytes key (AES-128).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the code is working and the documentation has something wrong as the output, remember when trying to decode to decode the IV and the cipher into HEX